# java: parse output of execute command

Tags: java, pocketsphinx

i am running jdk on windows 7. I try to run a external software (pocketsphinx_continous.exe) within my java application. The software runs permanently (pocketsphinx_continous.exe) and prints some output to the console which i like to read by my java application.

if i run "pocketsphinx_continous.exe" with some params from the commandline all works well and i see the output from the software. After killing the process, i try to run it within my java application. But java print no output to the console.

This is my code:

```
public void start(){
    try {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] commands = {"D:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/bin/Release/x64/pocketsphinx_continuous.exe", "-hmm", "d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us", "-lm", "d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin", "-dict", "d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict", "-samprate", "16000/8000/48000", "-inmic", "yes"};
        Process proc = rt.exec(commands);


        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Java will only print "Here is the standard output of the command:" and nothing more. But it wont crash, its still running without any errors. It seems to me java will wait until the executed command is finished until it prints anything. But the software will run permanently and print some times new results ...

Any ideas?

Best regards

Mike

Comment: Try using this method  `public int read(char[] cbuf, int off,   int len)    throws IOException` here ` while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {` instead of `readLine` because maybe your output is never ended in `\n`.

Comment: If this program is written in C or C++, and possibly some other languages, by default output to a terminal is done line by line, but output to a file or pipe is buffered -- and **Java uses pipes** to communicate with a child process. Try `yourcommandline | findstr .` at command prompt; if you don't see the output there you won't in Java either.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the following:

```
    Process p = null;
    ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("D:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/bin/Release/x64/pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -lm d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin -dict d:/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict -samprate 16000/8000/48000 -inmic yes");
    try {
        p = b.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ( (line = output.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using `ProcessBuilder` you don't have to separate parameters. Just copy the whole command in a `String`.

Comment: `Runtime.exec` also has an overload for the whole line, and overloads for the environment and workingdir. The only thing you can do with `ProcessBuilder` but not `Runtime` is inherit or redirect stdin/out/err.

Comment: This wont work either, it seems he stuck in the line "while ( (line = output.readLine()) != null) {". There is no error and no output!

Comment: Maybe the external application doesn't output line by line. Then try `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` as @ACV suggested.

Comment: Are you sure about what you said? `ProcessBuilder` is expecting an array of strings containing the executable and params individually, and I just found this out the hard way.